# Vue: passing onclick-method name via props

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to create components in a loop, passing properties to the child by name.

so:
`<card-base v-for="(card, i) in cards" :key="i" :heading="card.heading" :width="card.width" class="dashboard-card" :cardHeaderButtons="[{icon: 'minimize', fn: 'minimizeDashboardCard'}]">`

in my (child!) component i have defined the `minimizeDashboardCard` method,
and

```
                <v-btn icon flat class="header-button" v-for="(button, i) in cardHeaderButtons"
                       :key="i"
                       v-if="$vuetify.breakpoint.lgAndUp"
                       color="white"
                       @click.capture.stop="button.fn"
                >
                    <v-icon>
                        {{ button.icon }}
                    </v-icon>
                </v-btn>
```

the `{{ button.icon }}` works. but the fn doesn't

```
Uncaught TypeError: button.fn is not a function
    at !click (CardBase.vue?ac7a:32)
    at invoker (vue.esm.js?efeb:2027)
    at HTMLButtonElement.fn._withTask.fn._withTask (vue.esm.js?efeb:1826)
```

i also tried with `this[button.fn]`, but that doesn't work either.

the solution is probably super easy, but i don't see it right now. how can i pass the method NAME? (like for minimize, i want to have methods defined once in that card component and just have to pass the name to reuse it.)

thanks :)

Comment: As you have it now, `button.fn` is defined as a string. If `minimizeDashboardCard` is a method in the parent scope, just pass the function. `fn: minimizeDashboardCard`

Comment: but ```minimizeDashboardCard```is only defined in the child. that's why i want to pass strings and not define the "minimize" method in every place i use it around the app. (edited the original question to make it clear the method is only defined in the child method)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using a helper method ..

```
methods: {
  ...
  call(methodName) {
    this[methodName]()
  }
}
```

Then you can do this in your template ..

```
 <v-btn icon flat class="header-button" v-for="(button, i) in cardHeaderButtons"
                       :key="i"
                       v-if="$vuetify.breakpoint.lgAndUp"
                       color="white"
                       @click.capture.stop="call(button.fn)"
>
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe try `@click.capture.stop="eval(button.fn).call()"`

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_call.asp

Comment: unfortunately not :/
```Uncaught TypeError: button.fn.call is not a function
    at !click (CardBase.vue?ac7a:32)
    at invoker (vue.esm.js?efeb:2027)
    at HTMLButtonElement.fn._withTask.fn._withTask (vue.esm.js?efeb:1826)```

(both with and without parens)

Comment: works now, but i think it's cleaner with a helper function. but thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

pass `button` as parameter to a method like :

```
   @click.capture.stop="callBtn(button)"
```

in your methods :

```
  methods:{
      callBtn(button){
       button.fn();
       }
    ...  
     }
```

Comment: didn't work, it would still try to "call" fn (which is a string). in connection with Husam's answer, it worked now though. thanks to all of you!